# Ansible replace new line with three space followed by newline

Tags: replace, ansible, regexp-replace

I want to replace each “\n” with “   \n” But it shouldn’t replace in places like words having \n “C:\node” how to achieve this.

```
- set_fact:
    Value: “{{Str.replace(“\n”,”    \n”)}}”
```

Comment: [I don't see any problems with the above example task](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/51c3c3f9490f150e1f5619d18f1e70c4)

Answer (score 1):

Use single-quoted strings and put both *regex* and *replace* into variables. Then you have to escape '\' only once. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: value
      vars:
        str1: 'C:\node'
        value: "{{ str1|regex_replace(regex, replace) }}"
        regex: '\\n'
        replace: '    \\n'
```

gives

```yaml
  value: 'C:    \node'
```

If you put *regex* and *replace* in-line you have to escape twice because of the outside double-quotes. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: value
      vars:
        str1: 'C:\node'
        value: "{{ str1|regex_replace('\\\\n', '    \\\\n') }}"
```

You have to escape also twice if you double-quote *regex* and *replace* in variables. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: value
      vars:
        str1: 'C:\node'
        value: "{{ str1|regex_replace(regex, replace) }}"
        regex: "\\\\n"
        replace: "    \\\\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

The newline character `\n` is different than the two characters `\` and `n`, so inside your regex if you do not escape the `\` of the newline character it should not match the character `\` followed by `n`

For example, the regex `\n` matches the newline character but nothing in "C:\node"  while `\\n` will match "C:**\n**ode"

You can try to experiment with regex yourself in [regex101](https://regex101.com/)